# Node Inspector Console - Can't Execute Command, Goes to Newline Instead

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I am running node inspector and trying to run commands in the console.

However, I cannot run them. Instead of running, hitting enter goes to a new line.

Using any other console in chrome works fine, just not Inspector's.

Have tried restarting node and inspector. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have same issue, its mentioned also [here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/903). Seems like its happening for the latest chrome and someone could fix it by downgrading chrome to v51

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Chrome v54, v56 are having this issue for both mac and windows. The easiest solutions so far is downgrading your chrome to v51, and I think some one is working on a PR to fix this.

You can download V51 from here
http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac

===========================================================================

Another work around is to use command
`node --inspect --debug-brk index.js`

After running that, goto chrome, open
`chrome://inspect` you will see a page like this
[image]

Find the target and click the inspect, a debugger will be attached automatically and everything works from there. Just like it used to be in `node-inspect`, and the console works!

read this for more information

http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/06/01/node-v8-inspector-inspect.html

Comment: I'm having this problem in Chrome 55. Looking forward to the fix.

Comment: @trusktr I edited my answer, and that was a much better solution, please let me know if it works for you, thanks!

Comment: This is no longer a problem for me as I am on Chrome v55, but I haven't tried and confirmed the workaround. If it comes up again I will try these workarounds and confirm the answer as correct. If anyone else has tried these please feel free to elect this as the answer.

Comment: Used the second workaround successfully in v57 (64-bit) under Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for posting!